# How to connect on windows 10 through smb to external server shared folder

Tags: networking, windows-10, smb, sharing

I am trying to connect to external ip address through smb on windows 10 without any success.

```
\\server-ip:port\shareDirectoryName
```

So far I did try the following ports: 139,445 but without any success.

I know this is not firewall/antivirus issue, even when firewall is disabled problem still persists.

When I try to connect to the same external server on LINUX or MAC this problem does not appear. Everything works like it should.

Command on mac/linux:

```
smb://server-ip:port/shareDirectoryName
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your network firewall settings. Most firewalls (by default) enable network share traffic only on internal/local ip addresses.

Comment: Also, Windows only allows, by default, connecting to network shares on the current subnet.

Comment: Use the following command in Windows to enable File and Printer sharing across any subnets: `netsh firewall set service type = fileandprint mode = enable scope = ALL profile = ALL`

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same issue. Could not get access to ip-address...

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any error messages? 
Please try to ping the external server both with the IP address and the FQDN firstly.

There is no need to assign the port.
Just input " \\server name or IP address" to have a test in Windows Explorer.

Comment: The only error message I get is following: Can not gain access to... Btw I know that there is no need to assign the port, the only reason why I am doing that is because I forward this port on the router.

Answer (score 0):

My Window 10 Pro would not let me access my old NAS drive, although I could enter the drives administrative setup.  Here is the work-around I used.  While in the admin setup I created a SMB share, folder named DATA.  I went back to Windows Desktop and clicked on This PC icon.  In the file explorer window I right clicked on "This PC" and choose "add a network location."  That started "add a network location wizard."  Follow the prompts and enter the address in the input box in this manner:  \\198.192.1.116\DATA  (the address is the one assigned to the NAS drive by DHCP)  That's it.  You can give it a name so you know it's your NAS. It shows up under This PC in file explorer.  You can even map to it with the same procedure.  BTW, it would probably be prudent to assign the NAS a static address in your router so it doesn't change. That would break the path and the map.